# No white space in the beginning and at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regex-negation

In my Angular application (Typescript)I want to check an `input` against white spaces in the beginning and at the end of the inserted value by the user.

The following Regex `^[^\s].+[^\s]$` and its `RegExp` equivalent `/[^\s].+[^\s]/` is the most common answer I found. But the `test` function of this regex does not return correct boolean.

What is the correct RegExp that returns false if a string contains whitespaces in the beginning, at the end or both?

```js
function myFunction(){
var myStr=document.getElementById("reader").value;
var regex1=/[^\s].+[^\s]/;
var regex2=new RegExp('[^\s].+[^\s]','i');
var result1=regex1.test(myStr);
var result2=regex2.test(myStr);

document.getElementById("writer1").value=result1;
document.getElementById("writer2").value=result2;
}
```

```html
<input id="reader" type="text" placeholder="string" onChange="myFunction()"/>
<p> regex:<input type="text" id="writer1"/></p>
<p> with constructor:<input type="text" id="writer2"/></p>
```

Comment: The first regex is correct `^[^\s].+[^\s]$` - why aren't you using that and instead use something that **not** an equivalent?

Comment: Your reg exp should probably match the stare and end of the string.

Comment: @VLAZ How to use `^` and `$` in javascript? and why it is NOT equivalent?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi you literally just use that `^[^\s].+[^\s]$`. And `[^\s].+[^\s]` is not an equivalent because it doesn't have the start/end of line anchors.

Comment: @epascarello well running the code snippet, shows something else

Answer (score 1):

Using the first pattern `^[^\s].+[^\s]$` you string must have at least 3 characters because the negated character class requires a match and `.+` will match 1+ times any char except a newline.

The second pattern `[^\s].+[^\s]` is not anchored and will also allow partial matches.

If you also want to match `a` or `aa` you could use a negative lookaround to assert that the string does not end with a space or tab and start the match with a non whitespace char.

```
^(?!.*[ \t]$)\S.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*[ \t]$)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a space or tab at the end of the string
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times except a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM6MTs/1)